# MAMP just ONE virtual host not working

Tags: apache, wordpress, mamp, httpd.conf

I wanted to start a (my first) wordpress project on my mac.
I run apache with MAMP, and wanted to make another (I allready have a few) virtual host for this particular project.
I added the host to my httpd.conf and etc/hosts file as i've done many times before.
When I browse to the url i've chosen I just end up in the directory that i've specified as root folder in my MAMP settings.
Apache seems to ignore the changes made in the httpd.conf file, but if I remove (rename) the httpd.conf file (to _httpd.conf) it apache doesn't start. so it looks like changes to this file are ignored, BUT if I put something wrong in the file apache doesn't start either...
this is what I put in the httpd.conf file to add a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/site_dir/"
  ServerName local.sitename.com
  <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/site_dir/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

can this have anything to do with WP?

greets,
R.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

Try putting it in the conf/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf instead and try
where port 80 is whatever port you have apache running on (:80 by default on windows)

and try not to use .org .com or any ending common on the web in your server name/alias use if you are developing the project on your localhost use something like sitename.local instead.

On Mac:
Not sure how it would work

On Ubuntu 11.04:
 I just:

1. Set up a different vhost file for each site inside of /etc/apache2/sites-available
2. Then enable the site via a2ensite or just make a copy to the file using cp to the sites-enabled folder (all this is done via the ssh or a terminal on mac)
3. I then reload and restart apache and wallah!

I'm having a similar problem on one of my ubuntu servers.  I'm doing something that I've done several times but all of a sudden it doesn't work.  Go figure, lol!  Typo?  Who knows, definitely scour the web, an answer is sure to surface.

Comment: You should create a symlink in sites-enabled rather than copy the vhost (with `ln -s`). That's also what a2ensite does, btw.

Comment: the OP specifically mentioned he uses a mac computer, and your solution doesnt include anything useful for mac